# PSpice voltage controlled switch not switching

Tags: switches, pspice

I am attempting to implement a simple voltage-controlled switch in a larger circuit design in PSpice. I am a student and have not yet worked with this component in the OrCAD suite. The switch is controlled by a pulse voltage source and should, if my design were correct, open between 400us and 450us as V2 falls from 1V to 0V. However, the switch remains closed. Can you see any flaws in my design which might be resulting in this error? I have attached the schematic of this section of the design as well as a transient analysis of the circuit. Please let me know if more information is required. The switch resistance is 1MOhm open and 1uOhm closed.

[image: Switch Schematic]

[image: Transient Analysis]

Comment: try forcing the solver to a shorter time step (or the scope)

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thank you for your comment. I decreased the max time step from 1us to 10ns and increased the pulse width of V2 to 1ms to provide more time for the switch to actuate in case that was the problem. Unfortunately, I did not see a significant difference in the transient result. The switch still does not open.

Comment: Try fiddling with VH and VT, pspice got rid of their online help so I can't help you on this one.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that out. If that doesn't work I may just need to find a different way to perform the type of timed switching I am looking for.

Comment: I could've sworn that PSpice's proprietary `VSWITCH` component uses `VON` and `VOFF`.  It's not based off of SPICE3's standard voltage controlled switch which uses `VT` and `VH`.  Unless they made a specific compatibility carve-out for the SPICE3 switch in recent versions???

Comment: @SteKulov I also noticed that, but I don't have PSpice, their own manual says nothing about it, yet OP's picture shows it working, so I concluded it must be allowed. I wonder if the behaviour is like in LTspice, with a distintion between positive and negative hysteresis.

Answer (score 2):

If the values for `Ron` and `Roff` are exactly as you wrote them to be, then you're in for a surprise: *MOhm* translates to **milli**Ω. SPICE is not case sensitive, so the distinction between *milli* and *Mega* is done by writing `m` (milli) and `meg` (Mega). The values, as they would be after the correction, are fine, just remember to not tempt the Devil by setting a ratio larger than `1e12`; that's the recommended maximum. Also, units don't matter, they're silently discarded by the parser, but as long as you don't get errors, they can be added.